# time out detection and handling in running javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute an arbitrary js function when user click on a button in browser.

I want to **stop it and alert** if its **execution time exceeds 4 seconds**. (for example if it's infinity loop)

now **browser freeze** when i run a code contains infinty loop, etc. And I want to avoid this.

also I cant manipulate function. I just can have a function call.

Comment: This isn't possible (as far as I know), not if you can't change the function implementation. Why would you have functions with infinite loops in them?

Comment: this is function which user wrote, and i dont know anything about it.

Comment: @nnnnnn: thanks, is there any multi-threading  in js?

Comment: Modern browsers will give the user an error message after a while (specific delay depends on the browser). But I don't think there's any way to code a test yourself because JS isn't multi-threaded (unless you count web workers, which I'm pretty sure won't work for this purpose).

Comment: May be u better use a recursive function so that you can get a stackoverflow error when it tooo... much...

Comment: @AkhilSekharan what should i put in this recursive function? i cant understand what you mean.

Comment: I meant calling the function by itself. I might be able to help if you could post a sample code.